# Xcode 4.6 does not recognize SDL.framework

Tags: sdl, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.6

Consider me a complete and utter newbie wehen it comes to compiled languages (and to Xcode IDE in general)

I've followed some tutorials on setting XCode up to work with SDL frameworks, they seem to be a bit dated, designed to work with OSX 10.6 or 10.7 so I also made sure I'm following the readme's within SDL dmgs.

I can't figure out where in the file system do I put my SDL.framework (or any other framework like SDL_image.framework, for that matter). I've tried

```
/Library/Frameworks
/System/Library/Frameworks
~/Library/Frameworks
```

When I open Xcode and browse for frameworks to add / link, the SDL frameworks are nowhere to be found.

When I opened a template project downloaded from
https://github.com/Ricket/HelloSDL
All the framework references were colored red, as in 'error' or 'does not exist'.

Can someone please tell me, where the hell do I put those things?
Oh, and any up-to date Xcode + sdl settup tutorial would be of great value to me too!

Comment: I've just tried showing Xcode the path to SDL.framework manually and it ran the linked `HelloSDL` application fine. It just can't find it anywhere on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the SDL.Framework downloaded or the SDL2.Framework compiled if you are working on that version it doesn't matter too much where you put it as long as you link it correctly in your project. I generally tend to keep them in `/Library/Frameworks`

Step 1. Select your build target and choose the `Build Settings` section. Then search for `Framework Search Paths` or alternatively scroll down to the `Search Paths` section and expand it if needed. Set the value of `Framework Search Paths` to be the location you have placed your frameworks.

Step 2. To then include the framework in your project, select your build target and choose the `Build Phases` section. Expand `Link Binary With Libraries` and click the + button. In the popup window which appears you need to click `Add Other` then browse to the location you placed the framework e.g. `/Library/Frameworks` and select the framework to add.